# Three vectors are given, choose a basis for the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, vectors

> The subspace $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{4}$ is spanned by the vectors
>   $v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  2\\  3\\  0 \end{pmatrix},
> v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
> -1\\  5\\  7\\ 
> -1 \end{pmatrix}, v_{3}=\begin{pmatrix} 5\\ 
> -4\\ 
> -5\\  2 \end{pmatrix}$. From these vectors, choose a basis $B$ of $S.$

$I: x-y+5z=0$

$II: 2x+5y-4z=0$

$III: 3x+7y-5z=0$

$IV: -y+2z=0 \Leftrightarrow y=2z$

insert $IV$ in $I: x-2z+5z=0 \Leftrightarrow x+3z=0 \Leftrightarrow x=-3z$

insert $I$ and $IV$ in $II: 2(-3z)+5(2z)-4z=0 \Leftrightarrow -6z+10z-4z=0 \Leftrightarrow 0=0$

insert $I$ and $IV$ in $III: 3(-3z)+7(2z)-5z=0 \Leftrightarrow -9z+14z-5z=0 \Leftrightarrow 0=0$

So $y=2z$ and $x=-3z$

$\begin{pmatrix}
-3z\\ 
2z\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}= z\begin{pmatrix}
-3\\ 
2\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \text{Basis } B= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
-3\\ 
2\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} \right \}$

But the problem is the basis isn't of same size as the given vectors.. : /

I think everything I did is wrong but how can I do such a task correctly?

I'm looking for solutions, not for hints as I have tried this all day long with no real success. It's no homework anyway.

Comment: Try to keep in mind what $x,y,z$ each **represent** in your calculations.  Through your calculations you seem to be trying to find $x,y,z$ such that $x\cdot v_1 + y\cdot v_2 + z\cdot v_3=0$ (*the zero vector of $\Bbb R^4$*).  Assuming your calculations are correct, you have found that $-3v_1+2v_2+1v_3=0$ which implies something about the linear independence of $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

Comment: In particular, since you found an $x,y,z$ such that $xv_1+yv_2+zv_3=0$ with at least one of $x,y,z$ nonzero you found they are *dependent* vectors.  So, the three vectors span at *most* a two-dimensional subspace.  What dimension *is* the subspace they span?  We learned it can't be a 3 dimensional.  Is it a 2 dimensional, a 1 dimensional or a 0 dimensional?  Note that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not multiples of one another which implies...  Now, for a $k$-dimensional subspace, **any** set of $k$ linearly independent vectors in that space work as a basis for it.

Comment: if $v_1,v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent, they form a basis.  If it is the case that they were not linearly independent, then select as vectors many as are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put your three vectors as rows of a matrix. Next, reduce by rows the matrix. Finally, all the rows that become all-zero at the end of the reduction you can throw them away, and what you're left with is a basis for the span of the original vectors. In our case$${}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&0\\
\!-1&5&7&\!-1\\
5&\!-4&\!-5&2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2+R_1,\,R_5-5R_1}\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&0\\
0&7&10&\!-1\\
0&\!-14&\!-20&2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3+2R_2}\longrightarrow$$$${}$$

$$\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&0\\
0&7&10&\!-1\\
0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, the first two **original** vectors span the subspace:

$$\;\text{Span}\{\,(1,2,3,0)^t,\,(-1,5,7,-1)^t\,\}=\text{Span}\{\,(1,2,3,0)^t,\,(-1,5,7,-1)^t,\,(5,-4,-5,2)^t\}\;$$

or you can instead take the two vectors you got in the last step above:

$$\text{Span}\{\,(1,2,3,0)^t,\,(-1,5,7,-1)^t\,\}=\text{Span}\{\,(1,2,3,0)^t,\,(0,7,10,-1)^t\,\}$$

as you wish.